# Getting exception "PhpOffice \ PhpSpreadsheet \ Reader \ Exception" when parsing specific csv file

Tags: phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

Something in a csv file I am trying to import using Maatwebsite's Laravel Excel package (which uses PhpOffice's PhpSpreadsheet package) is causing the import to blow up with the following exception:

```
PhpOffice \ PhpSpreadsheet \ Reader \ Exception
C:\Users\jasona\AppData\Local\Temp\laravel-excel-mbAxJfb8Hm5yF5BKNzhJ0MZmmMzAHQnR is an Invalid Spreadsheet file
```

I believe there is some data in the file causing this to blow up as if I reduce the number of records in the file down to a few, it works just fine.  Problem is, I do not know what I am looking for as the root cause of this.  Has anyone else run into this issue?  What am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Switching the file format from csv to xlsx resolved this issue.  I tried changing the delimeter to a pipe symbol, but that didn't make a difference.

Not sure what bad data was in there.

Comment: my data is like: `POINTER THERMOMETER 0-600°C` . so how can i resolve that? from this error?
`Failed to load C:\xampp\htdocs\flash-forgepvtltd\storage\framework\cache\laravel-excel\laravel-excel-RQAxNiFX5gE94jMGX8wsef1swxo0ezOy.html as a DOM Document`